# How to add rounded background or ellipsical shape on Tizen native wearable?

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

I want to achieve a shape that is like rectangular button. But the close I got is adding a rectangle as the background. This is rectangular and I could not find elm bubble on wearable.

Code:

```
Evas_Object *bg1 = evas_object_rectangle_add(tab);
EXPANDFILL(bg1);
evas_object_color_set(bg1, 255, 255, 255, 255);
elm_table_pack(tab, bg1, 0, 0, 1, 1);
evas_object_show(bg1);
```

So how can I achieve this ellipsical background or rectangle with a corner radius?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there are no APIs that support rounded rectangle and ellipsical shape

You can use evas_object_image or elm_image to load the desired shaped image.

(https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/guides/native-application/user-interface/efl/primitive-graphical-objects/evas-objects)

(https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/guides/native-application/user-interface/efl/ui-components/wearable-ui-components/image)

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Fyi, Those shape drawing functions (including rounded rectangle) will be supported in Tizen 6.0

Comment: Good to hear. Thank you.